# Tastypie resource usage in django view

Tags: jquery, django, tastypie

I am working on on a web application and in future we have a plan to also develop iphone app for this. For this purpose we decide to use tastypie and make rest base framework.

I have developed a resource for adding value in one model and it works fine using jquery. 
Now I have to create a form in django. I don't know how to use this resource API in django views.  Should I use urllib and connect with my API or I should do it in old django manner instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [relevant part of Tastypie's Cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-your-resource-in-regular-views). Good luck ! :) It suggests that you use your resources in views directly (no urllib). See the provided link for an example.